# "Installation failed since the device already has a newer version of this application" Black-box Robotium testing Android Studio

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, robotium, black-box-testing

I have a black-box Robotium test working in Eclipse. I have imported the test into Android Studio. In the gradle file I've added:
 - Dependency to Robotium library: *androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.1'*

- The package of the app under test in the attribute: testApplicationId *"package.app.under.test"*

When I run the test I get the Exception:

*
*"Installation failed since the device already has a newer version of this application. In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application."*
*

I tried to uninstall the app, re-install, change the version of the app but I cannot run the test.

Does anyone know how to run a black-box Robotium test in Android Studio, for an app without the source code available?
Is correct to add the package of the app under test in the *testApplicationId* attribute.